# how to determine the algorithm used to generate a private key from a .pem file using java

Tags: java, openssl, pkcs#8

I'm trying to read a private key from a .pem file in PKCS#8 format, the problem I've faced is that these kind of files have this header
  `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`
so there is no information about the algorithm used to instantiate the key, my question is:
 is there a method to know the algorithm without decoding the key (which is base64) and see the algorithm modifier, also if there is a way to know the length of the key..
help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Using [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) and modifying the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919048/bouncy-castle-pemreader-pemparser), I came up with this to get your answers.

Note: This code will only work with non-encrypted private keys.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dsa.BCDSAPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.BCRSAPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;

public class PemKeyInfo 
{
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    String privateKeyFileName = "C:\\privkeypk8.pem";

    File privateKeyFile = new File(privateKeyFileName); // private key file in PEM format
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(privateKeyFile));
    Object object = pemParser.readObject();

    pemParser.close();

    JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");

    PrivateKey privkey = null;

    if (object instanceof PrivateKeyInfo)
    {
       privkey = converter.getPrivateKey((PrivateKeyInfo) object);
    }
    if (privkey != null)
    {
       System.out.println("Algorithm: " + privkey.getAlgorithm()); // ex. RSA
       System.out.println("Format: " + privkey.getFormat()); // ex. PKCS#8
    }
    if (privkey instanceof BCRSAPrivateKey)
    {
       System.out.println("RSA Key Length: " + ((BCRSAPrivateKey)privkey).getModulus().bitLength()); // ex. 2048
    }
    if (privkey instanceof BCDSAPrivateKey)
    {
       System.out.println("DSA Key Length: " + ((BCDSAPrivateKey)privkey).getParams().getP().bitLength()); // ex. 2048
    }
    if (privkey instanceof BCECPrivateKey)
    {
       System.out.println("EC Key Length: " + ((BCECPrivateKey)privkey).getParams().getOrder().bitLength()); // ex. 256
    }
  }
}
```

Update: I've edited the code above to give key lengths for RSA, DSA, and EC keys.

Comment: when I viewed the type of the pemParser.readObject() it was one of BCRSAPrivateKey, BCDSAPrivateKey, and BCECPrivateKey depending on the file I was trying to import,, using ur code I get unable to convertKeyPair "exception I think", and I've tried to use instanceof operator but also didnt work :(

Comment: I've edited the code above to give key lengths for RSA, DSA, and EC keys.  I also listed the entire class including the imports so there is no confusion between which classes are Bouncy Castle classes and regular Java classes.  This code should work for all PKCS#8 formatted RSA, DSA, and EC private keys.