# How to read contents of a password protected file?

Tags: java, file, pem

I am trying to read data from password protected PEM file to generate public and private key from those data. I have the password and I need to pass that password during opening the file. But I haven't any option in java to do that.

Need emergency assistance on this. It would have been much better if I could get a code example for this.

*EDITED:*

My current code is -

```
public void readPrivateKey(String filePath)

{
  File fp = new File(filePath);

  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fp);

 DataInputStrean dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
byte [] keyBytes = new byte [(int) fp.length()];
dis.readFully(keyBytes);
dis.close();
String temp = new String(keyBytes);
String privateKeyPem = removeUnnecessaryTags(temp); //this function returns a string after removing String like this "BEGIN......."
byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(privateKeyPem);
ASN1Sequence primitive = (ASN1Sequence) ASN1Sequence.fromByteArray(decoded);
Enumeration <?> e = primitive.getObjects();

BigInteger bigInt = ((DERInteger)e.NextElement()).getValue();
int version = bigInt.intValue();
BigInteger modulus = ((DERInteger)e.NextElement()).getValue();
BigInteger publicExp = ((DERInteger)e.NextElement()).getValue();
//... all the values has been retrieved in this way
}
```

Comment: Did you check `new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build(password);` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919048/bouncy-castle-pemreader-pemparser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are taking about RSA key-pair.

You can do it without using Java like this,

```
openssl rsa -in MYFILE.pem -pubout > MYFILE.pub
ssh-keygen -f MYFILE.pub -i -m PKCS8
```

If you need to do this in Java, refer to link given by @m0skit0 in comments.

---

Comment: But my key is not encrypted. The file is only password protected. Does this imply that if the file is password protected then the key is also encrypted?

Comment: Well I am sharing my code in the edited part of my code. Then I think you will get my point :)