# What is the Java equivalent to PHP's openssl_open with passphrase protected key?

Tags: java, php, encryption, openssl, passphrase

I have some encrypted data that was generated with PHP [openssl_seal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-seal.php) function.

I need to decrypt (open) that data with Java.

I've found an article that explains it (http://blog.local.ch/en/2007/10/29/openssl-php-to-java/), but this does not cover the scenario when the key needed to decrypt the data is in turn passphrase-protected.

How should I modify the solution mentioned in the article to use a passphrase-protected key?

Code of the mentioned article:

```java
package ch.local.common.util.crypto;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

/**
 * For decrypting data encrypted with PHP's openssl_seal()
 * 
 * Example - String envKey is the Base64 encoded, RSA encrypted envelop key
 * and String sealedData is the Base64 encoded, RC4 encrypted payload, which
 * you got from PHP's openssl_seal() then;
 * 
 * <pre>
 * KeyPair keyPair = OpenSSLInterop.keyPairPEMFile(
 *          "/path/to/openssl/privkey_rsa.pem"
 *      );
 * 
 * PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
 * String plainText = OpenSSLInterop.decrypt(sealedData, envKey, privateKey);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @see http://www.php.net/openssl_seal
 * @author Harry Fuecks
 * @since Oct 25, 2007
 * @version $Id$
 */
public class OpenSSLInterop {

    private static boolean bcInitialized = false;

    /**
     * @param cipherKey
     * @param cipherText
     * @param privateKey
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String decrypt(String cipherText, String cipherKey, PrivateKey privateKey)
    throws Exception {

        return decrypt(cipherText, cipherKey, privateKey, "UTF-8");

    }

    /**
     * @param cipherKey Base64 encoded, RSA encrypted key for RC4 decryption
     * @param cipherText Base64 encoded, RC4 encrypted payload
     * @param privateKey
     * @param charsetName
     * @return decrypted payload
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String decrypt(String cipherText, String cipherKey, PrivateKey privateKey, String charsetName)
    throws Exception {

        byte[] plainKey = decryptRSA(Base64.decode(cipherKey), privateKey);
        byte[] plaintext = decryptRC4(plainKey, Base64.decode(cipherText));
        return new String(plaintext, charsetName);

    }

    /**
     * Loads a KeyPair object from an OpenSSL private key file
     * (Just wrapper around Bouncycastles PEMReader)
     * @param filename
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static KeyPair keyPairFromPEMFile(String filename)
    throws Exception {

        if ( !bcInitialized ) {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            bcInitialized = true;
        }

        FileReader keyFile = new FileReader(filename);
        PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader(keyFile);
        return (KeyPair)pemReader.readObject();

    }

    /**
     * Returns a KeyPair from a Java keystore file.
     * 
     * Note that you can convert OpenSSL keys into Java Keystore using the
     * "Not yet commons-ssl" KeyStoreBuilder
     * See - http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/utilities/
     * e.g.
     * 
     * $ java -cp not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.8.jar org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder \
     *     "privkey password" ./privkey.pem ./pubkey.pem 
     *   
     * @param filename
     * @param alias
     * @param keystorePassword
     * @return
     */
    public static KeyPair keyPairFromKeyStore(String filename, String alias, String keystorePassword)
    throws Exception {

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        File keystoreFile = new File(filename);

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
        keystore.load(in, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
        in.close();

        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
        Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
        PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

        return new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey)key);

    }

    /**
     * @param cipherKey
     * @param privateKey
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static byte[] decryptRSA(byte[] cipherKey, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        return cipher.doFinal(cipherKey);

    }

    /**
     * Defaults to UTF-8 as the output encoding
     * @param plainKey Base64 encoded, RSA encrypted key for RC4 decryption
     * @param cipherText Base64 encoded, RC4 encrypted payload
     * @return decrypted payload 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static byte[] decryptRC4(byte[] plainKey, byte[] cipherText)
    throws Exception {

        SecretKey skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(plainKey, "RC4");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(cipherText);

    }

}
```

Usage according to the article:

```java
KeyPair keyPair = OpenSSLInterop. keyPairFromPEMFile("/path/to/openssl/privkey_rsa.pem");
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
String plainText = OpenSSLInterop.decrypt(sealedData, envKey, privateKey);
```

thanks!

Comment: thanks for the title edit, I forgot the "java" part :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to modify the `keyPairFromPEMFile` method on the provided code to something like this:

```java
public static KeyPair keyPairFromPEMFile(String filename, final String password) throws Exception {

    if ( !bcInitialized ) {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        bcInitialized = true;
    }

    FileReader keyFile = new FileReader(filename);
    PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader(keyFile,  new PasswordFinder() {

        public char[] getPassword() {
            return password.toCharArray();
        }});

    return (KeyPair)pemReader.readObject();

}
```

Now you can specify a password to retrieve the PEM file that stores the key by creating a new `PasswordFinder` instance to return the given password as an array of char.

Note that I'm using bouncycastle version 1.46. If you move to newer versions you will need to adapt your code in several ways, specially the passwordFinder will be replaced with a `new Password()` instance. You can refer to this other questions regarding such adaptations: [Bouncy Castle : PEMReader => PEMParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919048/bouncy-castle-pemreader-pemparser)