# BouncyCastle PEMParser readObject Factory/Builder/Adapter Design Pattern or any Utility class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, bouncycastle

I have read a lot of bad examples on PEMParser:

```
int myFunc(String privateKeyFileName, char [] password) {
     File privateKeyFile = new File(privateKeyFileName); // private key file in PEM format
     PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(privateKeyFile));
     Object object = pemParser.readObject();
     PEMDecryptorProvider decProv = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build(password);
     JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
     KeyPair kp;
     if (object instanceof PEMEncryptedKeyPair) {
        System.out.println("Encrypted key - we will use provided password");
        kp = converter.getKeyPair(((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) object).decryptKeyPair(decProv));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unencrypted key - no password needed");
        kp = converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) object);
    }
}
```

[Bouncy Castle : PEMReader => PEMParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919048/bouncy-castle-pemreader-pemparser)

Also here:
[How to read .pem file to get private and public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787571/how-to-read-pem-file-to-get-private-and-public-key)
https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser
https://www.javatips.net/api/org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.pemreader

Does BouncyCastle provide some factory method for this?

The only thing I found is: [org.apache.sshd.common.keyprovider.FileKeyPairProvider](https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=mina-sshd.git;a=tree;f=sshd-common/src/main/java/org/apache/sshd/common/keyprovider;h=7c2704d4f862c0e816abb4383c3bb41a092d1048;hb=HEAD)  (Apache Mina SSH Java client implementation). I think something like this could be a part of BouncyCastle itself or Apache Common libraries (fileutils / stringutils).

Is there any factory/builder method or some design pattern implementation or is everyone doing a production code like `if (object instance of xxx)` and solving the problems on the go?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand your question. What kind of key(s) are you trying to read with Bouncy Castle's PEMParser (Private Key / Encrypted Private Key / RSA Private Key / Public Key / Certificate) ? BC's PEMParser is like a "Suice knife" that is been able to read a lot of formats...

Comment: All keys: Private Key / Encrypted Private Key / RSA Private Key / Public Key / Certificate

Comment: So it is question about the library and more about architecture/design. I don't need help with the actual implementation how to read a key. The question is if there is some nicer code encapsulating this ugly piece of Java object with no interface and no design pattern.

Comment: Can someone answer please?